# How to solve unexpected token

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, cat

For I in cat test.txt
Cat file.txt|head -n $i|tail -n 1| cut -f w >>out.txt

Error is syntax error near unexpected token cat

Comment: `for` and `cat` need to be lower-case

Answer (score 0):

You need a do for the loop. The syntax is also wrong.

```
for i in $(cat test.txt); 
 
        do 
        cat file.txt | head -n $i | tail -n 1 | cut -f w  >> out.txt;
        done;
```